# Autofill to last active row

Tags: vba, excel, autofill

The code I'm using is:

```
Range("U5:AK5").AutoFill Destination:=Range("U5:AK" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

Column A's data is dynamic and sometimes the last active row will already be 5 (same row as the formulas) or sometimes row 4 only. If data in column A goes down to row 4, I don't get an error. But if it goes to row 5, I get an error. Obviously if it goes farther than 5, I don't get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check to see if you are going to fill any rows below row 5 before proceeding.

```
Dim lr As Long
With Worksheets("Sheet3")
    lr = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If lr > 5 Then _
        .Range("U5:AK5").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("U5:AK" & lr)
End With
```

It isn't entirely clear from your narrative whether you consider 'filling down' to row 4 is acceptable. If it is then just change that to `lr <> 5`.

Comment: hey Jeeped. i used the code for all tabs requiring auto-fill and it worked perfect as expected from someone with your skills. thank you so much. :-)

Comment: What changes do I need to make in the code if the LR (last row) is taken from another worksheet in the same spreadsheet?